# How to get the Docker Container Id from inside a running docker image via Java API?

Tags: java, docker, java-ee-7

Not finding anything on the University of Google so checking here.  I have an enterprise application running on an application server inside a docker image.  During the running time, the enterprise application needs to use a Java API call to obtain the Docker Container Id that it's running in.  How is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, when docker runs a container it should set the hostname with the id of the container, so just reading the environment variable `HOSTNAME` (or the file `/etc/hostname`) should do it.

If this does not work, provide more information about your setup.

Comment: This works as long as you don't specifically set the hostname as far as I can tell. otherwise the hostname becomes what you set it to and the container ID is gone

Comment: On Openshift v3 this appears to return the Pod ID rather than the ID of the docker image